# SQL: Insert new records from 1 table to another

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I have two tables with students (using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition). I Need to write a procedure, so that if 1st table has new students, the second one gets updated as well

this doesnt work and I dont know why:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CHECK_NEW]


AS
begin transaction

declare @tempId int
declare @tempName varchar

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR  
SELECT kId, kName
FROM table1

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1  
INTO @tempId, @tempName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

if (SELECT sId FROM table2) NOT IN(@tempId)
insert into table(sId, name) values(@tempId, @tempName)

END

commit
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "this doesnt work " - not a useful description. BTW you don't need to use a cursor...

Comment: @MitchWheat I just dont have anything to add, the procedure compiles without Errors but the 2nd table is not updated wwhen I execute it, and I have no clue why

Comment: why are you scanning the wole table? why not add a trigger (has its own issues) or insert from code -> keep only one place to add to table 1 and there start a txn and do this. Else you might have situation where db is over worked if you ever have more TPS (Txns per second) under load

Comment: @marc_s sorry, Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: OK - and **what version**? 7.0? 2000? 2005? 2008? 2008 R2? 2012? And which edition: Standard? Web? Enterprise? Express?

Comment: @MitchWheat Standard edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CHECK_NEW]


AS
Begin Try
begin transaction
         Insert into Table2(ulid,Id,Name) 
     Select newid() as ulid, Id,name from ( Select Row_Number() over(Partition by a.id order by a.id) as row, a.Id,a.name from Table1 a  where
not exists(Select * from Table2b where a.Id=b.Id)) t where row =1
Commit
End Try
Begin Catch
RollBack
End Catch
```

Comment: the Problem is, the 2nd table has a column "uId" for unique identifier (the 1st one doesnt have it) that doesnt allow null, and when adding the values I call my function newid(), to generate it. jow can I add this value, when I insert from select?

I mean:  Insert into Table2(uId, Id, Name), while first value is added from the function newid() and two others from this insert?

Comment: @user2336688 hard to understand what you want?

Comment: table2 has These columns: uId (a random value generated by a function, does not allow null), id and Name. the uId doesnt exist in the first table, only in the second one. if I add it the way you wrote, uId will remain null and this wont work. how can I insert uId (calling the function newid()) at the same time, as inserting 2 other columns from a select as you wrote?

Comment: ok...ulid is generate by a function right what its input paramenter and what it return type,

Comment: Input is void, just newid(), and it generates an "unique identifier" data type, the column uId accepts it

Comment: doenst work properly, he adds it so many times, as there are records in the table 2. if a have 10 rows in table 2, it will be added 10 times

Comment: as said, if I have 10 records in table2, it will add each not present record from table1 10 times

Comment: if i have in table2 (uId:. id:1, Name: test; uId:.. id:2, Name: test; uId:... id:3, Name: test;) and in table1 (id:5, Name: test;), it will add (id:5, Name: test;) 3 times to table2, so many times as there are unmatching records in table2

Comment: @user2336688 i updated my answer i used left join now try now

Comment: same,   doenst return anything

Comment: try now @user2336688 it will work this time i checked it already,,,here....http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97389/1 it will give those table 1 rows that are not present in table2

Comment: thanks, but now there is another Problem XD : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef685/1 if I have multiple records in table1, a want to have them in table2 only once

Comment: i update my answer and updated sql fiddle is here 
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef685/6

Comment: gruopy doesnt give you name..in sql server 2008....any way glad finally your problem over best of uck....